# Links and buttons not firing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

**NOTE:** Upon narrowing it down, I think it might have to do with `position: relative` but I need to figure out what to do.

I have an application I am building from scratch, and none of the buttons or links are firing. I've narrowed down the problem to being within the CSS file, because when I remove the CSS all the buttons and links work.

The controller is binding information to the scope, like when i have `$scope.test = "hello";` it is bound to the DOM. However, none of the links or buttons are firing. I've tried a mix and match of different links and buttons and the cursor does not change to pointer when the cursor hovers over the link/button. What am I missing/forgetting?

At the bottom I've included the CSS.

**index.html**

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController" class="main-guy">
    {{test}}
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; background-color: blue" ng-click="info('please work')">Click</div>
        <div class="screen-outside">
          <a href="http://www.google.com">This is a test</a>
            <div class="screen-inside" ui-view>
                <!-- Screen changes with click -->
            </div>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">This is a test</a>
      <button ng-click="hey()">HEY!</button>
            <div class="screen-footer">
                <div class="buttons-bar">
                    <div class="buttons-holder">
                        <div class="button-ind"><a ng-click="screen()">Rider</a></div>
                        <div class="button-ind"><button class="btn" ng-click="screen()">Audio</button></div>
                        <div class="button-ind">Power</div>
                        <div class="button-ind"><button class="btn" ng-click="screen()" value="Bluetooth"></div>
                        <div class="button-ind"><a ui-sref="#" ng-click="screen()">{{test}}</a></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-block-container">
            <div class="bottom-block left-block"></div>
            <div class="bottom-block right-block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**MainController.js**

```
$scope.hey = function(){
    $window.alert("YAY!!!!");
};

$scope.test = 'Hello';

$scope.screen = function(){
    console.log("Hey!!!");
};

$scope.info = function(msg){
    console.log("Hey!!!");
}
```

**style.css**

```
.main-guy {
    position:relative;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: #050505;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:-1000;
}
.screen-outside {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #888888;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute; 
}
.screen-inside {
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    height:80%;
    width:85%;
    background-color: #666666;  
}
.screen-footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
}
.buttons-bar {
    margin:auto;
    height: 80%;
    width: 70%;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #707070;
}
.buttons-holder {
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.button-ind {
    margin:auto;

    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    height:40%;
    background-color: #535353;
    font-size:15px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.btn {  
  background-color: transparent; border: 0; padding: 0; width:100%; height:100%;
}
.footer-block-container {
    margin-top:80%;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:25%;
    position:absolute;
}
.bottom-block {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#3A3A3A;

}
.left-block {
    float:left;
}
.right-block {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem: on all my DIV elements, I need to have `z-index: *some value* ;` set wehere I have `position` set in elements of the DOM. That solved the problem right away.